# Why cant I use a constant when pattern matching even though it implements PartialEq and Eq?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, ip-address

I want to filter out the IPv4 localhost address by using the constant `net::Ipv4Addr::LOCALHOST` when pattern matching:

```
use get_if_addrs; // 0.5.3
use std::net;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    assert_eq!(
        "127.0.0.1".parse::<net::Ipv4Addr>().unwrap(),
        net::Ipv4Addr::LOCALHOST
    );
    {
        let ifaces = get_if_addrs::get_if_addrs().unwrap();
        for iface in ifaces {
            match iface.addr {
                get_if_addrs::IfAddr::V4(get_if_addrs::Ifv4Addr {
                    ip: _,
                    netmask: _,
                    broadcast: None,
                }) => (),
                get_if_addrs::IfAddr::V4(get_if_addrs::Ifv4Addr {
                    ip: net::Ipv4Addr::LOCALHOST,
                    netmask: _,
                    broadcast: _,
                }) => (),
                get_if_addrs::IfAddr::V4(addr) => println!("{:?}", addr),
                get_if_addrs::IfAddr::V6(_) => (),
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I get an error

```
error: to use a constant of type `std::net::Ipv4Addr` in a pattern, `std::net::Ipv4Addr` must be annotated with `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]`
  --> src/main.rs:19:25
   |
19 |                     ip: net::Ipv4Addr::LOCALHOST,
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:23:17
   |
23 |                 get_if_addrs::IfAddr::V4(addr) => println!("{:?}", addr),
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unreachable_patterns)] on by default
```

[`std::net::Ipv4Addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html) does have implementation for `PartialEq` and `Eq`, so what does that error mean? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message states:

> must be annotated with `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]`

This is [not true for `Ipv4Addr`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libstd/net/ip.rs#L702-L709), which implements it manually, instead of deriving it.

Instead, use a *match guard*:

```
use get_if_addrs; // 0.5.3

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let ifaces = get_if_addrs::get_if_addrs().unwrap();
    for iface in ifaces {
        match iface.addr {
            get_if_addrs::IfAddr::V4(get_if_addrs::Ifv4Addr {
                broadcast: None, ..
            }) => (),
            get_if_addrs::IfAddr::V4(get_if_addrs::Ifv4Addr { ip, .. }) if ip.is_loopback() => (),
            get_if_addrs::IfAddr::V4(addr) => println!("{:?}", addr),
            get_if_addrs::IfAddr::V6(_) => (),
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

You may also consider introducing some nesting:

```
use get_if_addrs::{IfAddr, Ifv4Addr}; // 0.5.3

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let ifaces = get_if_addrs::get_if_addrs().unwrap();
    for iface in ifaces {
        match iface.addr {
            IfAddr::V4(addr) => match addr {
                Ifv4Addr {
                    broadcast: None, ..
                } => (),
                Ifv4Addr { ip, .. } if ip.is_loopback() => (),
                addr => println!("{:?}", addr),
            },
            IfAddr::V6(_) => (),
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

---

[RFC 1445](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1445-restrict-constants-in-patterns.html) explains the underlying decisions more:

> - Introduce a feature-gated attribute `#[structural_match]` which can be applied to a struct or enum `T` to indicate that constants of type `T`
>     can be used within patterns.
> - Have `#[derive(Eq)]` automatically apply this attribute to the struct or enum that it decorates. Automatically inserted attributes do
>     not require use of feature-gate.
> - When expanding constants of struct or enum type into equivalent patterns, require that the struct or enum type is decorated with
>     `#[structural_match]`. Constants of builtin types are always expanded.
>
> The practical effect of these changes will be to prevent the use of
>   constants in patterns unless the type of those constants is either a
>   built-in type (like `i32` or `&str`) or a user-defined constant for which
>   `Eq` is **derived** (not merely *implemented*).